# Reinforcement learning using predicted human responses?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Reinforcement learning is used a lot when rules are known. For instance in games, where the rules and possible actions are clearly defined, then reinforcement learning is often used.

The problem here would be : Is it possible to apply reinforcement learning to a domain involving human responses ?

A typical example problem being an advertising company (such as Google or Criteo) that is paid per click. They want to maximize their revenue so they want to maximise P(click)*price_pair_by_advertiser - cost_of_the_impression.

The problem I see is that human behavior does not obey strict rules. 
The solution I was thinking about is then to use a model that mimics/simulates human response (here, given the page the user is browsing and the ads displayed, what is the probability of click). Then you can feed that "human model" into the reinforcement learning algorithm.

Then, I'm thinking that if you solved the problem of assessing P(click) then you solved the problem. So I'm wondering if in fact my idea was just stupid (solving the "human response problem" always solves the bigger problem) ? If it isn't then has there been research done on it/ is there a keyword for that kind of algorithms, so that I can google it ?